# How can I ensure that the $ ". $discount_offer_on_totals." is based on the site url as well

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple websites using the same database table for discount. However, the return section returns value for the first url when the if statement is true, irrespective of the website used. How can I ensure that the $ ". $discount_offer_on_totals." is also based on the site url

```
list($discount_offer_on_totals) = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($connect,"select discount_offer from orders_discounts")); 
    if ( $total < $discount_offer_on_totals ) {
    return "Order total must be $ ". $discount_offer_on_totals." or more to qualify for discount!";
    }
```

[Discounts Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTCjT.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use where condition in the query

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT discount_offer FROM orders_discounts WHERE url = ? ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: Use parameterized querys. Injecting `$_SERVER` variables(or any variable for that matter) into a query is a bad idea.

Comment: @Andrei, kindly suggest improvements using  parameterized querys. I am not an expert in programming but learning